# How does one Dockerize and deploy a Pytorch deep learning model via SSH?

Tags: python, docker, pytorch, nvidia-docker

I'm having trouble understanding how to deploy a PyTorch docker image on a remote machine that has an Nvidia GPU. I'm relatively unfamiliar with Docker in general, and this is my first time using Docker for the purposes of deep learning.

I am able to train my models on my local machine without problems via a trivial command-line call to `python main.py`, which is what I'm familiar with. But now that I have to SSH into this machine I'm required to use Docker.

So far I have pulled a few images without really knowing what I'm doing. So, here's what got me the furthest so far:

First, I transferred my code to the machine via a GitLab repository -- nothing fancy. I also transferred some large datasets via SSH into the parent directory of my GitLab repository. I.e., it looks something like this:

```
DeepLearningProject/
├── Data_folder/
│   ├── datasets/
│   ├── results/
│   └── etc...
└── MyGitFolder/
    ├── lots_of_python_files.py
    └── main.py
```

Next, I pulled the following image via `docker pull anibali/pytorch:1.4.0-cuda10.1` as the version numbers satisfy our requirements.

Here's where the guessing game got out of hand. So, I have an image with Pytorch and all the Nvidia stuff, but I'm still missing my own python package dependencies. I'm not sure where the installation hereof takes place, for example in a requirements.txt file. Thus, python reports missing packages when I run the following, as per a tutorial I found online:

```
docker run --rm -it --init \
  --gpus=all \
  --ipc=host \
  --user="$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
  --volume="$PWD:/app" \
  anibali/pytorch:1.4.0-cuda10.1 python3 main.py
```

So, I thought I could perhaps enter a bash terminal by excluding the `python3 main.py` part of the above command. This just opens the python3 interpreter interface. I assume this is due to the image's Dockerfile(?) ending on `CMD ["python3"]`, and I'm unsure as to how I can install my requirements through this.

As requested, please find an example of the error message for the missing python packages below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    from model import (generate_model, load_pretrained_model, make_data_parallel,
  File "/app/model.py", line 4, in <module>
    from models import resnet, resnet2p1d, pre_act_resnet, wide_resnet, resnext, densenet
  File "/app/models/resnext.py", line 9, in <module>
    from utils import partialclass
  File "/app/utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

I assume this image does not have `sklearn` in its `requirements.txt`. Is there a way I could 'pipe' in my own `requirements.txt` when executing `docker run`? I believe this to be my main issue here.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: "python reports missing packages when I run the following" can you post the exact and complete error message?

Comment: @Berriel Thanks, I've supplemented the question with the error message for clarity.

Comment: You have to define a Docker file using the `pytorch:1.4.0-cuda10.1` as base , copy your code, and install dependencies and run that final image.